# Install Jenkins in OpenShift from Docker Image

Tags: docker, jenkins, openshift

We have tried to install Jenkins in OpenShift 4.3 from the Docker jenkins/jenkins:lts image. When navigating to the route URL, all that is presented is:

```
Jenkins-Agent-Protocols: JNLP4-connect, Ping
Jenkins-Version: 2.222.3
Jenkins-Session: <redacted>
Client: <redacted>
Server: <redacted>
Remoting-Minimum-Version: 3.14
```

In the log file, there is a message:

```
Jenkins initial setup is required. An admin user has been created and a password generated.
Please use the following password to proceed to installation:

<redacted>

This may also be found at: /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword
```

What do we do with this password and how do we do the initial setup?

Comment: You need to use the same solution as [Kubernetes](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/jenkins-docker/blob/master/2/README.md#first-log-in). Instead of running `kubectl exec` you should use `oc exec`  you can read more [here](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/nodes/containers/nodes-containers-remote-commands.html)

Comment: Also, the initial password is the one needed to unlock your Jenkins installation. Once you type that password, you will be able to access and configure Jenkins. To do so, go to the URL of your SERVICE. Jenkins configuration can be done using the console ( web ui )

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue deploying the jenkins/jenkins:lts image on Openshift.  I noticed that the Route that was automatically create, was for the agent port (5000) not the admin console UI port (8080).  So I manually created another Route that points to the UI port (8080), and this worked.

Note: Once you get to the UI, you can use that initialization password you saw in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to jenkins setup doc https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/
I would suggest you go through and understand about the initialAdminPassword.

After generating this password, the doc suggests to go to localhost:8080.
You should use the {ip for your docker instance}:8080 to see the setup screen of jenkins using a browser. It is pretty straightforward from there.

Comment: This is not on localhost - it is deployed on OpenShift. OpenShift creates a route that is only listening on port 80. Going to that route only shows what I describe above and does not prompt for a password.